# Magento: Set Group_Price and Tier_Price => Duplicate entry SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: magento

I'll try to import products with tier prices and group prices. First time it works great, but if I try to update it, I'll get an error:

```
Versuche zu speichern:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Doppelter Eintrag '4463-0-0-0' für Schlüssel 2
```

(Duplicate entry for primary key 4463-0-0-0).

I've found a "solution" in a german blog. It recommends to delete all rows from the tables `catalog_product_entity_group_price` and `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` for the entity_id ( = ProductId).

```
  $dbc = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
              $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
              $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product').'_group_price';
              $dbc->query("DELETE FROM $table WHERE entity_id = ".$product->getId()."");
```

This works great! But is there a better solution for doing this? A class method? And why does the magento import process not delete this entrys before try to inserting the rows?

Another solution was the following code. But it requires a product->save() action, which was not good for the import performance:

```
$product->setTierPrice( array()  );
$product->save()
$product->setTierPrice($pid["my_tier_price_array"]);    
$product->save()
```

Is there a better solution than a "double save()-method" or directy delete from the database?

Comment: I have the same problem. Watching this question with great interest!